# How to show file names in File Transfer?

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStorm has a nice File Transfer log:

```
[24.07.2014 12:36] Upload to server.net
[24.07.2014 12:36] Upload to server.net completed in less than a minute:
   1 file transferred (36,4 Kb/s)
```

Anyway I could make it show the name of the file it transferred?

Comment: Good question and... why in the world would the default be to show the least amount of details??!! When do we ever want to know as little as possible about the files we are uploading to overwrite other files??? 0_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select File | Settings for Windows or select File | Default Settings for set option for all projects.

[image]

Comment: Much better details in this image - the current answer's image is obscure

Answer (score 15):

`Settings/Preferences on Mac | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options`

Change `Operations logging` level to a more detailed one (`Details`).

[image]

Comment: I have wanted this for years! I can't believe it took me this long to search for it. Thanks much @LazyOne

Comment: And another time, THE AMAZING PHPSTORM! Thank you so much